# Error "Schema "information_schema" not found;" running "migrate up" on H2 database

Tags: h2, coldbox, commandbox

I'm testing h2 database in a ColdBox application (on Lucee) ...
I can connect to database with Quick but I'm not able to run migrations...

this is the error displayed in CommandBox after migration init and migration up

```
ERROR (5.2.1+00295)
Schema "information_schema" not found; SQL statement:SELECT 1 FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_name" = ? AND "table_schema" = ? [90079-172]   
MigrationService.cfc
SELECT 1 FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_name" = 'cfmigrations' AND "table_schema" = 'testAppDB'
```

Both Application.cfc and box.json use ENVIRONMENT settings:

```
# ColdBox Name and Environment
APPNAME=tastApp
ENVIRONMENT=development

DB_BUNDLEVERSION=1.3.172
DB_PORT=
DB_USER=sa
DB_BUNDLENAME=org.h2
DB_CLASS=org.h2.Driver
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DRIVER=org.h2.Driver
DB_SCHEMA=appDB
DB_DATABASE=appDB
DB_CONNECTIONSTRING=jdbc:h2:/Users/elena/coldbox-examples/testApp/database/appDB;MODE=MySQL;
DB_PASSWORD=
```

h2 was downloaded from Lucee download page and saved in /lib folder (I've added dependencies in box.json)

this is the grammar settings:

"defaultGrammar":"AutoDiscover@qb"

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Elena

---

UPDATE - May 18

Thanks to Evgenij,

now I am able to query the latest version of h2, 1.4.200, which accepts the setting (CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS = TRUE) which makes all identifier names (table names, column names) case insensitive.

Unfortunately migrations with commandbox-migrations still give me error:

these are the current configurations I am using:

```
"cfmigrations":{
    "migrationsDirectory":"resources/database/migrations",
    "schema":"INFORMATION_SCHEMA",
    "connectionInfo":{
        "bundleName":"com.h2database",
        "bundleVersion":"1.4.200",
        "password":"",
        "connectionString":"jdbc:h2:/Users/elena/coldbox-examples/testApp/database/appDB;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;",
        "class":"org.h2.Driver",
        "username":""
    },
    "defaultGrammar":"AutoDiscover@qb"
}
```

this is the last error:

```
> * > CLI v5.2.1 > 10:59 AM > ~/coldbox-examples/testApp/ > testApp (1.0.0) >
 lucee 5.3.7 (running) >
> migrate up
ERROR (5.2.1+00295)                                                                                                                                             Unable to resolve com.h2database [108](R 108.0): missing requirement [com.h2database [108](R 108.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)) 
Unresolved requirements: [[com.h2database [108](R 108.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0))]
  caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException
Unable to resolve com.h2database [108](R 108.0): missing requirement [com.h2database [108](R 108.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[com.h2database [108](R 108.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

H2 1.3.172 is very old and it can't properly emulate non-standard lower case `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` from MySQL.

You need to use a recent version of H2 (such as 1.4.200, for example) with `;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` appended to JDBC URL, `;MODE=MySQL` alone is not enough.

Comment: Thank you Evgenij; I've downloaded suggested version and saved in in lib fonder of my coldbox application, but now I've this error: The OSGi Bundle with name [org.h2] in version [1.4.200] is not available locally (/Users/elena/.CommandBox/server/A6BB937D9E26EE318D085EF2B2DB46FA-testApp/lucee-5.3.7.47/WEB-INF/lucee-server/bundles; What am I missing?

Comment: It was renamed to `com.h2database` in the version 1.4.198.

Comment: ok... what about this error:Unable to resolve com.h2database [106](R 106.0): missing requirement [com.h2database [106](R 106.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[com.h2database [106](R 106.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0))]
  caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException
  Unable to resolve com.h2database [106](R 106.0): missing requirement [com.h2database [106](R 106.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)) Unresolved re...

Comment: another question, I hope the last: In H2 1.3.172 the bundle name was 'h2.org' and driver class name was 'org.h2.Driver... in H2 1.4.199 the bundle name is 'com.h2database'; what the driver class name is?

Comment: It is still `org.h2.Driver`, but it's rarely appropriate to use it directly, since Java 6 / JDBC 4.0 drivers are registered automatically.

Comment: Hello Evgenij, unfortunately the class name is mandatory for commandbox-migrations :( ... with this configuration ["migrationsDirectory":"resources/database/migrations",     "schema":"INFORMATION_SCHEMA", "connectionInfo":{ "bundleName":"com.h2database", "bundleVersion":"1.4.200",   "connectionString":"jdbc:h2:/Users/elena/coldbox-examples/testApp/database/appDB;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;",     "class":"org.h2.Driver"}, "defaultGrammar":"AutoDiscover@qb"]
I had the error posted on May 13 at 16:31
Thanks for your help anyway